# Bing Streetside Static Image

Tags: bing-maps

I'm evaluating Bing Maps as an alternative to Google since my company already has Bing licensing.  Is there a way to embed a static Streetside image into a web page?  With Google this can be accomplished using a URL (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=150x150&location=39.6105900,-104.8872449&fov=50&heading=235&pitch=10).

I've been searching online, but haven't found a way to do this with Bing, even in the [Create a Custom Map URL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn217138.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) article. The proposed application has an interactive map with pins.  Specific pinned building addresses and detailed building info is below the map. Next to the building info we need to display a static thumbnail image of the building (or at least something in the vicinity).

Answer (score 1):

Bing Maps currently does not provide a static REST service for Streetside imagery. Streetside imagery can only be displayed on the Bing Maps V8 web control and the Windows 10 map control at this time.

Comment: That's a bummer.  Thanks for the info!